# <div> with min-width value grows but then doesn't return to its min-width size

Tags: html, css

Despite my search on stackoverflow and google, I couldn't find a solution to my problem:
I have a `<div>`, which contains another div within another div, so:

```
<div class="father" style="min-width: 800px;">
    <div class="child">  
        <div class="grandchild">  
            ...content, which can make this div grow beyond its father's and grandfather's size...  
        </div>  
    </div>  
</div>
```

Here, if the content makes its containers grow over 800 pixels, and then the content is changed to a width less than 800px , outer divs still remain oversized and don't return to their original size. Even pressing F5 or CTRL+F5 doesn't help.

Is there a way to fix this without using javascript?

Thanks in advance!

ps: Even if I used 4 spaces, the code doesn't seem to be indented, sorry for that.

Comment: You were missing the closing quotes on all three of your class names.. If you copy-pasted that code from your actual page, that may be part of your issue.

Comment: no I didn't copy paste, but many thanks for your correction.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the width and set `overflow:hidden` to the father `div`

`.father{overflow:hidden;}`

Comment: I tried that, but the content (which is an image in an img tag) is cut off beyond the borders of the father div, unfortunately.

Comment: You can check here on my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/naveed_ahmad/BvtHW/ the red color is for the father div with no width and the grandchild is 300px wide and 300px tall. See the father has been stretched to accommodate the inner child.

Comment: yes, but it doesn't shrink to a minimum width, when it is not required that it is that big. never mind, I think I will have to use javascript.